# How can I inject the same object via different interfaces?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, robotlegs

Using Robotlegs 2.0, is it possible to declare a singleton in a context and inject it in multiple classes, where each injection is requesting a different interface?

The class to inject:

```
 class MyClass implements IFoo, IBar {}
```

Injection site 1:

```
 class NeedFoo {
    [Inject]
    public var foo:IFoo;
 }
```

Injection site 2:

```
 class NeedBar {
    [Inject]
    public var bar:IBar;
 }
```

I want both injections to be for the same instance, but if I create two mappings, then each gets its own instance:

```
 injector.map( IFoo ).toSingleton( MyClass );
 injector.map( IBar ).toSingleton( MyClass );
```

So I ended up doing this:

```
 var instance:MyClass = new MyClass();
 injector.map( IFoo ).toValue( instance );
 injector.map( IBar ).toValue( instance );
```

Is there a way to just say that this object should be provided for any interface that it implements, rather than individually for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, but it's a bit convoluted and really unclear ATM. We're going to provide some syntactic sugar for it in the future, but for the moment you can do this:

```
injector.map( IFoo ).toSingleton( MyClass );
var provider: DependencyProvider = injector.getMapping( IFoo ).getProvider();
injector.map( IBar ).toProvider( provider );
```

or

```
var provider: DependencyProvider = injector.map( IFoo ).toSingleton( MyClass ).getProvider();
injector.map( IBar ).toProvider( provider );
```

Comment: Yes, it could do with some sugar.. but it does the job! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a ticket in an issue tracker somewhere?